# Concurrent http requests

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, httprequest

I am running the following method on multiple threads:

```
private JSONObject jsonFromUrl(String requestUrl)  {
    try {
        URLConnection connection = new URL(requestUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        return  (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(
                new InputStreamReader(response,charset));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error("Exception while sending request: " + requestUrl + " error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new JSONObject();
    }
}
```

Are the HTTP requests being processed in parallel? Does making the requests in this way blocks the other threads from sending a request until the first response arrives?

Comment: Answer: Parallel, Yes. Blocking other instances, No.   Do you have reason to suspect that you can't have multiple instances of URL downloads happening across different threads?

Comment: Lags are longer than expected, and can't determine if this is as a result of the connection or lack of parallelism

Comment: Do you close your InputStream anywhere?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht - I do.

Comment: Well, my question indicates that I do not see that, as it is not in your method. As the InputStream is opened in the method - where is it closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method can be invoked from different threads. No shared variable are present there so no concurrency issue. However you could optimize the process, by having a pool of connections (sockets connections) to reuse connections and for faster responses. 
Having no way to control the sockets, you could end up by having slow time response. Of course we are discussing about open socket connections and the possibility of the sever to keep the socket opened (Keep-Alive header)